# Customize access denied per pattern

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I use Grails 3.1.X and Spring.Core.Security 3.1
I have this configuration in my application.groovy file:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'bcrypt'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.exceptionMappings = [

        [exception: AccountExpiredException.name, url: '/expiredAccount']
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [

        [pattern: '/', access: ['permitAll']],
        .....
        [pattern: '/test/**', access: ['ROLE_ADMIN']],
```

When I log in and try to reach /test the filter stop me, which is fine, and tell me I don't have permission.
I'd like to redirect it to a particular controller/action or to a gsp to show custom page. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to be redirected to that custom page when you lack access rights on any page, or only for `/test/**`, having a different behavior for other pages?

Comment: Only for /test/**